# Cannot compile program which uses another module in cpp

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, lib

I am writing a cpp program where I want to include another custom lib so that I don't need to add multiple files etc. for compilation.
My project structure is:

```
apps/
    - /test
    - /test2
```

I have included test lib in test2's makefile as:

```
STATIC_LIBS     += test
CFLAGS          += -I$(SWIFT_ROOT)/apps/test/
LDFLAGS         += -L$(SWIFT_ROOT)/apps/test
```

But still at compilation I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Makefile:

```
ENABLE_VERSION_API=1

TARGET = test2

SRCS += \
        main.cpp \
        test2.cpp \
        \
        # Add more

LIBS            +=
STATIC_LIBS     += test
EXT_STATIC_LIBS += ssl crypto ssh2 curl protobuf
EXT_LIBS        += z

CFLAGS    += -I$(SWIFT_ROOT)/include/google/protobuf/
CFLAGS    += -I$(SWIFT_ROOT)/libs/src/test2/
CFLAGS    += -I$(SWIFT_ROOT)/apps/test/
LDFLAGS   += -L$(SWIFT_ROOT)/apps/test
include $(SWIFT_ROOT)/build/app.mak
```

Execution command -

```
    g++ -I/root/include/google/protobuf/ - 
   I/root/libs/src/test2/  -std =c++17 -Wno-unused-but- 
   set-variable -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-deprecated- 
   declarations -Wno-parentheses -Wno-switch -Wno-literal    -suffix - 
   Wno-conversion-null -Wno-format-contains-nul  -D_THREAD_SAFE - 
   D_GNU_SOURCE -D__USE_GNU .builtobjs/main.o .builtobjs/test2.o -L 
   /root/apps/test -Xlinker --start-group -lz -ldl 
   -lpthread     -lrt -luuid -lstdc++fs -Wl,-Bstatic -lssl -lcrypto - 
   lssh2 -lcurl -lprotobuf -ltest -Wl,-Bdynamic - 
   Xlinker --end-grou    p -Wl,-rpath,/opt/swift/lib64 -Wl,- 
   rpath,/opt/swift/lib -o test2
```

Here my main question is how to add a custom lib inside another module. I have followed standard steps like including LIB then CFLAG (-I) and LDFLAG (-L). But is there any other improvement which needs to be done here?

Comment: Show the compilation command.

Comment: @kiner_shah It's a Makefile. I execute just make using these flags

Comment: How do you build the `test` library? It *is* built?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes test lib is already built

Comment: From a complete clean, please do a verbose build that shows the library being built. Then copy-paste the full and complete (verbose) output into your question, so we can see the actual commands that are executed.

Comment: `-L$(SWIFT_ROOT)/apps/test`  or `-L$(SWIFT_ROOT)/apps/test/` ?

Comment: No, I was debugging and pasted that directly. Ignore that.
/apps/test this is correct one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude added execution command

Comment: Where does `build/app.mak` come from?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat app.mak is just used to for cleaning, version info. I have pasted actual command in my edit plz check

Comment: Offtopic: `$(SWIFT_ROOT)` this is strange!

Comment: @MarekR that's env variable, assume SWIFT_ROOT = /root here

Comment: Your command just shows that `-ltest` gets passed to the linker. But who creates `libtest.a`, and does it get created at all?

Comment: OMG: Your execution command `g++ -I/root/include/google/protobuf/  ....` is bad. Are you using `make` or not? You should copy paste invocation and outcome of `make`.

Comment: In the `apps/test` directory, is there a file named `libtest.a`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, there isn't any libtest.a 
It should have been there but something is wrong as for other libs those .a files are present

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out by some people. I was not having .a file in my directory. Generated it using ar command, working fine now.